# html5-dropmenue does not open after hovering over the menue

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML5 and CSS. So my question is probably very basic and very naive. My apology for that.
To practice I am developing a header menu with drop down sub menu. I primarily hide the drop down menu by setting its display property to none, after hovering on the parent I set the display to block. But it seems like hover can't change the display value. Also it is worth mentioning that my html page is using flex box in order to have grid layout. 
here is the html file:

```
<div class="menue">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Woman</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
          </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Flyers</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
        </ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and here is the css file:

```
.menue {
  background: #fc575e;
}

nav{
  height:40px;
  width: 960px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0,auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #112233;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li{
  float:left;
  width:140px;
  height:40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #fc575e;
}

nav ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover ul li{
  display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover{
  background-color: #223433;
  color:#f0f1f5;
}
```

It seems like my hover action does not doing its job to change the display value of sub-menu to block.
I was wondering if some one could give me a hint?
It is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

your css seems to be working fine. what you want to do is wrap both the `<a>` and `<ul>` tag inside an `<li>`

```
<li>
     <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Davi has it right, but you could also change

```
nav ul li:hover ul li{
  display: block;
}
```

for

```
nav ul li:hover + ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

[Heres a jfiddle of it working](https://jsfiddle.net/ez0L5oa2/)

By the way, when you hover over a menu button, whenever the submenu wants to show up, it will displace all other elements in the original menu

Also, here is a [nice tutorial](https://alistapart.com/article/dropdowns) on what you want to do specifically

Answer (score 0):

I know @JSelser has already provided a working answer. Yet, I felt mine could be helpful to another person. I went through this tutorial http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-a-dropdown-menu-with-html-css and adjusted to satisfy your menu.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 <style>
 .clearfix:after {
 display:block;
 clear:both;
 }

 /*----- Menu Outline -----*/
 .menu-wrap {
 width:100%;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 background:#3e3436;
 }

 .menu {
 width:1000px;
 margin:0px auto;
 }

 .menu li {
 margin:0px;
 list-style:none;
 font-family:'Ek Mukta';
 }

 .menu a {
 transition:all linear 0.15s;
 color:#919191;
 }

 .menu li:hover > a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#ffffff;
 background:#696969;
 }

 .menu .arrow {
 font-size:11px;
 line-height:0%;
 }

 /*----- Top Level -----*/
 .menu > ul > li {
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 font-size:19px;
 }

 .menu > ul > li > a {
 padding:10px 40px;
 display:inline-block;
 text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }

 .menu > ul > li:hover > a{
 background:#2e2728;
 }

 /*----- Bottom Level -----*/
 .menu li:hover .sub-menu {
 z-index:1;
 opacity:1;
 }

 .sub-menu {
 width:160%;
 padding:5px 0px;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0px;
 z-index:-1;
 opacity:0;
 transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
 box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 background:#2e2728;
 }

 .sub-menu li {
 display:block;
 font-size:16px;
 }

 .sub-menu li a {
 padding:10px 30px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration: none;
 }

 .menu-title{
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #fc575e;
 color: #000000;
 }

 a.menu-title{
 color: #000000;
 }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div class="menu_wrap">
 <nav class="menu">
 <ul class="clearfix">

  <li><a class="menu-title" href="#">Home <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu-title" href="#">Woman <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>  

  <li><a class="menu-title" href="#">Men <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu-title" href="#">Kids <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu-title" href="#">Flyers <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">New Arrival</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Casual</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gown</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bridesmade</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li><a class="menu-title" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```